# Google Apps Script and fetching JSON with UrlFetchApp

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am trying to retrieve JSON from a website using UrlFetchApp

I have learned over the last few days that Google Apps Scripts (GAS) does not support encoding  logon credentials in the url, which is the preferred method for accessing the target website.

The website does not support using headers to provide basic authentication parameters such as:

```
Logger.log('Basic Auth in header');
  var url2 = 'http://website.com'
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, {
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode('logon parms')
   },
   muteHttpExceptions: true
 });
 Logger.log('Response Code: ' + response.getResponseCode());
}
```

I get a 'Not found' error with the above, but it is apparently authenticating successfully, since if I change the password, it returns a 'Unauthorized' error.

My question - is there any other way to fetch JSON using GAS, or am I out of luck?

Comment: You question has nothing to do with JSON, it's an specific issue with the site you're trying to access. If you don't provide a more detailed test-case (or at least the link to the site you're trying to access) we cannot help you.

Comment: My question was more about GAS than JSON - I'm trying to find out if there are any workarounds for GAS not supporting URL encoded logon credentials.

Comment: It should work, but without anything we can try it's difficult to help.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem; I experimented with hard-coding my authentication code in the string rather than fetching it at runtime.  This isolated the problem; it seems that something about the formatting of the computed value at runtime must be messing things up.  Haven't worked out what the issue is yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this seems to fix the problem, but writing the code as follows should fix your problem (it worked for my case).  Just create the `auth` string outside the `response` initialization.

```
Logger.log('Basic Auth in header');
var url2 = 'http://website.com';
var auth = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode('logon parms');
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2, {
   headers: {
     'Authorization': auth
   },
   muteHttpExceptions: true
 });
 Logger.log('Response Code: ' + response.getResponseCode());
}
```